# Why does filter removes index 0 from my array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, filter

I just wanted to confirm something that's bugging me.

I'm still learning javascript and did a challenge today.
The challenge was to remove the value of every 2nd index.

I had to use the filter as part of the challenge and realised index2 on the code below doesn't return index 0 from the original array chopping off the value "a". So I got it to work by adding 1 to each of the indexes (index2 +1). Does it remove the 0 because filter() always returns true and 0 is seen as false?  Sorry I know it's probably a simple answer and thanks to anyone for taking the time to help me.

````
const nums = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"];
const index = 3;

const extractEachKth=(nums, index)=>nums.filter((item,index2)=>(index2 +1)%index!==0)

expected result ["a", "b", "d", "e", "g", "h", "j"]```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is wrong,  `filter() always returns true`. Rather filter will let those values pass the filter for which we are returning true. In your case you are returning true if `(index2 +1)%index!==0`.

When index2 == 0, `(index2 +1)%index!==0` => `(0+1)%3 !== 0` => `1 !== 0` which is true. Therefore it lets the 0th item from the array to be passed through the filter.

Before when you weren't adding +1 to the index2,

When index2 == 0, `index2%index!==0` => `0%3 !== 0` => `0!== 0` which is false. Therefore it filtered the 0th item and you didn't get that item.

Comment: Ok thanks I think I understand . So basically because 0 is false in the filter condition it doesn't return the 0 on the index unless I  add +1 which would then make it true?

Comment: Thanks for you help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look to the wanted indices, add one and take the remainer of the wanted `k` of three.

The result is a number of either 1, 2 (both are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)) or zero (this is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)).

If this value is converted to boolean, you get for one and two `true` and for zero `false`.

```js
const
    nums = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
    //       0    1         3    4         5    6         7  wanted indices
    //       1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10  all index + 1
    //       1    2    0    1    2    0    1    2    0    1  sum % 3
    //       *    *         *    *         *    *         *  take this truthy values
    extractEachKth = (nums, k) => nums.filter((_, index) => (index + 1) % k);


console.log(...extractEachKth(nums, 3)); ["a", "b", "d", "e", "g", "h", "j"]
```

Comment: Thats really helpful because  I've been trying to do something similar, it confirms that it adds on 1 to the 0 to make it pass. Thanks for putting that together.